# jQuery-Calx Auto Calculate

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

We have a registration form that uses jQuery-Calx to auto calculate the total of the selected items and would like to store the option value in a database after the form is submitted.

How should we define the value used in the calculation to do so? We want to calculate but also want to store “Event Name” if chosen into the database.

We have made some progress trying to follow comments here - http://www.xsanisty.com/project/calx2/comment-page-2/#comment-5678

Here is one of the drop down menus:

```
<select class="form-control" name="####" data-cell="A1">
   <option value="0">Please select</option>
   <option value="Event Name 15" data-next="15"  >Event Name $15</option>
   <option value="10">Ten</option>
 </select>
```

Here is script (not working):

```
 $('#registration').calx({
        data:{
        A1:{ value: $('[data-cell="A1"]').attr('data-next')}
        }
        });
```

We are trying to calculate the total of 5 drop down menus based on the "data-next" value instead of the select option value.

So we can then enter the option value "Event Name" into a database using php (we know how to do this part)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please provide sample code which you have worked or jsfiddle to debug easily

Comment: We have update with code samples...thank you.